# How to make connection with MQTT mosquito broker in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mqtt

I am trying to make a connection between my React web app and a mosquito broker which runs on docker. To do this i am using a [MQTT.js](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js) libary.

Here is my code so far:

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt')
const client  = mqtt.connect('tcp://172.19.0.4:1883')

console.log('mounted');

client.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('connected')
  client.subscribe('/powertest', function (err) {
    if (!err) {
     // client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
     console.log('error')
    }
  })
})
 
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer
  console.log(message.toString())
//  client.end()
})
```

This code is in the componentDidMount lifecycle event. When I run it, it shows no errors and it does not enter the on connect area. All I see in the console is the "mounted" log message.

How do I make it connect with the broker?

Comment: If you are running this in a browser then you will need to use WebSockets (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63611486/is-it-possible-to-make-mqtt-webpage-without-websocket/63612757#63612757) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42746139/javascript-client-for-mqtt-not-using-websockets)).

Answer (score -2):

Let's put the subscriber and the publisher in the same file:

```html
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org')

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('presence', function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
    }
  })
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer
  console.log(message.toString())
  client.end()
})
```